# Append data inside HTML5 picture srcset

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now im doing what you see here:

```
$("#wrapper").prepend('<header> <picture> <source media="(max-width: 999px)" srcset="Images/Small/Primary-Logo.png", "Images/Small/2x/Primary-Logo.png 2x", "Images/Small/3x/Primary-Logo.png 3x"> <source media="(min-width: 1000px)" srcset="Images/Big/Primary-Logo.png", "Images/Big/2x/Primary-Logo.png 2x", "Images/Big/3x/Primary-Logo.png 3x"> <img src="" alt="Main Logo"> </picture> </header>')
```

My question is if there is a way to smartly insert data to each of those sources without having to prepend large chunks of text.

for example leaving all srcsets"" empty and adding the url by appending.

How do I do this?

Comment: Yes you can by having unique references to `srcsets`

Comment: @Lshetty how? I cant find any info about it online. I tried replacing string names by putting a wrong url and then correcting it via javascript (trying to lazy load until user interacts with a certain button)

Answer (score 0):

So, first off, this:

```
srcset="Images/Small/Primary-Logo.png", "Images/Small/2x/Primary-Logo.png 2x", "Images/Small/3x/Primary-Logo.png 3x">
```

should be:

```
srcset="Images/Small/Primary-Logo.png, Images/Small/2x/Primary-Logo.png 2x, Images/Small/3x/Primary-Logo.png 3x">
```

Take a look at this for [more info](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/).

Here is a solution I can think of. See if this helps and also feel free to adapt this code to suit your needs.

```
var $wrapper = $("#wrapper");

var imageSrcs = {
    "tablet": ["Images/Small/Primary-Logo.png", "Images/Small/2x/Primary-Logo.png 2x", "Images/Small/3x/Primary-Logo.png 3x"],
    "desktop": ["Images/Big/Primary-Logo.png", "Images/Big/2x/Primary-Logo.png 2x", "Images/Big/3x/Primary-Logo.png 3x"]
};

$wrapper.prepend('<header> <picture> <source media="(max-width: 999px)" data-screen="tablet"> <source media="(min-width: 1000px)" data-screen="desktop"> <img src="" alt="Main Logo"> </picture> </header>')

$wrapper.find("[data-screen]").each(function() {

    var screenType = $(this).data("screen");
    $(this).attr({
        'srcset': imageSrcs[screenType].join(", ")
    });
});
```